# Amazon SES: How to set the return-path when using Raw mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

How can I set the return-path when sending e-mails in raw mode?

An example would be great.

Answer (score 3):

It may depend on what language SDK you are using but the SendEmailRequest class has a "ReturnPath" property that you set to an email address that you have access to and have also verified with Amazon.  The way it works according to their [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/#23) is that the return-path gets replaced out with an Amazon address and then they transparently forward the bounce email to the address you specified.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky. You can pass all the information for a raw mode send in the raw message. If you do, then you can pass the bounce email address as a header. Assuming you create the raw message from a .NET MailMessage, then you add it like this:

```
            mailMessage.Headers.Add("Return-Path", "bounce@yourdomain.com");
```

But, if you specify a Source parameter in your raw mode send, then Amazon docs say:

> If you specify the Source parameter, then bounce notifications and complaints will be sent to this email address. This takes precedence over any Return-Path header that you might include in the raw text of the message.